# setState doesn t work in a promise. State undefined with React

Tags: reactjs, promise, state, undefined

The problem is that I retrieve links from photos stored in firebase storage, I retrieve the links in an array (arrayurl) and everything works fine (console.log (arrayurl) shows me the link fix well) until I update the status with this.setstate ({array: arrayurl}). There is already the crash since it tells me that array is undefined. I know it's a sync problem but I can't get the array state to change in the promise. Try to move the setstate from place but always the same ...thanks for your help!

```
recupurl() {
  var arrayurl = []
  var storageRef = firebase.storage();
  var listRef = storageRef.ref('images');
  listRef.listAll().then((res) => {
    res.items.forEach((itemRef) => {

      var listRef2 = storageRef.ref('images').child(itemRef.name)
      listRef2.getDownloadURL().then((url) => {

        arrayurl.push(url);
        console.log(arrayurl);
        this.setState({
          array: arrayurl
        })

      });
    })
  })
}
```

Comment: Can you share the entire component, including your constructor/state.

Comment: You're calling `setState` in a `forEach` loop but you're always passing in the same array. React probably bails out of a render because the array is the same. Try making a copy of the array: `this.setState({ array: [...arrayurl] })`

Comment: Try changing recupurl() { } to recupurl = () => { }

Answer (score 0):

This happens when `this` does not mention class.
To solve this problem, I define a variable outside the block and pour `this` into it and use it inside my own block.

for example :

```
let T = this
let urls =[]
let storageRef = firebase.storage();
let listRef = storageRef.ref('images');
listRef.listAll().then( res => {
    res.items.forEach( itemRef => {
    let _listRef = storageRef.ref('images').child(itemRef.name)
    _listRef.getDownloadURL().then( url => {
    urls.push(url);

    console.log(urls);

    T.setState({array:arrayurl})
  
});  
})})}
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your help but if works partialy because it stock in array only one url and i have 16 pictures in my storage. the picture stocked is always diferent.

Answer (score 0):

You're mutating the state because of using the same array. The state should be updated in an immutable way. You also seem to have a problem with accessing `setState` because of `this` keyword referring to something other than the class, you can use an arrow function for that.

If you only want to update the state when the array is fully fetched instead of for each iteration, you can use this:

```
recupurl = () => {
    const arrayurl = []
    const storageRef = firebase.storage();
    const listRef = storageRef.ref('images');
    listRef.listAll().then((res) => {
        res.items.forEach((itemRef) => {
            const listRef2 = storageRef.ref('images').child(itemRef.name)
            arrayurl.push(listRef2.getDownloadURL())
        });
        Promise.all(arrayurl).then(urlArr => {
            this.setState({array: urlArr })      
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log(error)
        })
    })
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your help but if works partialy because it stock in array only one url and i have 16 pictures in my storage. the picture stocked is always diferent.

Comment: @ludo are you saying that in `state.array` there's only one element? Are you using the snippet in my answer?

Comment: Yes Ramesh, in the state.array there is only one url , and it should have 16. Yes i used your snippet , made copy paste. It works but it stock only one url. thanks fo your help

Comment: @ludo log `res.items` inside `then` block and see if it is giving you an array of more than one element.

Comment: yes , 'res.items'  gives me all urls but  this.state.array only one... strange .

Comment: @ludo - Okay what about `urlArr` try to log that inside the `then` block of `Promise.all`.

Comment: it's very strange because urlArr contains all urls. why in the setstate(array:urlArr) it copies only one?

Comment: @ludo - Where are you checking the updated state? And when is this function called? Add all related code to the question.

Comment: i check it in the render. ( console.log(this.state.array))